# Set content div to zero initially

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

I'm currently working on a site where I want my content div to start at 0 opacity when the page is loaded and then fade in to 100% after a short period of time.  I have this working just fine, however I'm not sure that how I'm handling this is the best way.

I seem to have read that it's best to not set things like opacity to zero in CSS, but rather set them to zero through jQuery.  This way, if a user doesn't have Javascript enabled, they are still able to see the content.

However, sometimes this method has its glitches, at least on my page.  Sometimes the HTML will load before the script has a chance to take over.  This results in the page initially showing, then disappearing, then fading as desired.  Not a big deal, but not as smooth as I would like.

Is there a better way to handle setting the opacity to zero initially?

Site is currently [here](http://www.nbsignsanddesign.com/NewSite).

Answer (score 1):

Although I think users with disabled javascript can be ignored, you could try something like this:

```
<style>
    #content{
        opacity:0;
    }
</style>

<noscript>
<style>
    #content{
        opacity:1;
    }
</style>
</noscript>
```

Comment: @pythonian29033, I gave an upvote because I can read the code, but I can't understand your answer.   "put your jquery in the to work as you would normally" has a syntax error :-p

Comment: better to use a programming language than a spoken language when speaking to programmers i guess

Comment: @pythonian29033 Sorry i didn't see your answer when i started writing mine.

Comment: @Andy sure you didn't :D don't sweat it man, I just wanna get to 1k rep

Comment: @pythonian29033 :P Welll yeah your answer was `2013-08-06 11:48:37` and mine at `2013-08-06 11:48:53`. But if you think i could read your answer, then writing my answer plus code in 16 seconds i'm honored :D

Answer (score 0):

I would say, put your jquery in the to work as you would normally have it work and after that add this `<noscript>` tag in and of course you won't be able to make the animation in jquery anymore, but you'll make the div opacity 100% in the noscript tag then

Edit: you could add the style in Joe's answer in the noscript tag, then you'll have alternate solutions :)